# ssh issues for github account

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I recently added added an ssh key to my github account using the steps recommended on the site.
When I try to clone repos from an organization that I am a member of, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am pretty sure I have correct access rights because I can clone using HTTPS just fine.
Does anybody know of an easy solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the URL used is the correct one (it is case sensitive), and uses the user '`git`' (not your GitHub account name)

```
git clone git@github.com:<aUser>/<aRepository>
          ^^^^
```

Second, if the problem persists, follow [Troubleshooting SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-ssh)

- The private key might have been created with a passphrase (meaning you would need ssh-agent)
- The environment variable `GIT_SSH` might be defined (and reference something else than openssh)
- ...